# Css mouseover not appearing

Tags: html, css, hover

Hi I have a div with a link however when you hover over the div the mouseover state doesn't change i.e. the mouse pointer doesn't change to a finger instead of a mouse

Unfortunately I am unable to replicate this error in jsfiddle it only seems t occur on my Wordpress installation

the address where it occurs is here http://stylrs.com/trustees/ (when you hover over individual names.)

Is there a reason for this?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.su-lightbox{ cursor: pointer }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! didn't even know bout that css property

Answer (score 0):

Those blocks arn't links at all. I see though you have a click event tied to them. Just give the block a `cursor:pointer` css style and it will look like a link

Answer (score 0):

try changing with css :

`.linkclass:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}`

 and please edit your question and give us your code. So, we can see the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it manualy like this :

```
.your div {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```